# base32 encode/decode on Meteor platform

Tags: meteor

For a reason I need to implement base32 encode and decode within the Meteor platform and I am having a very difficult time to find any package available for me to do it.  I found one for base64, but not base32.  Any pointer?

Comment: just use an npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use all npm packages by adding a Meteor package like this one: https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm.

Then create a 'package.json' file:

```
{
  "base32": "0.0.6"
}
```

And you are ready to use the package with `Meteor.npmRequire('base32')` on the server side.

Comment: I thought I've already got the meteorhacks:npm but apparently it was disabled by somebody else for whatever reason that is.  Re-adding the npm package get me through.  Thanks.